# Css-footer and background

Tags: css

I've been working on website recently and have come across a major problem :http://jimbob.webatu.com/index.html(you'll need to see the coding on the webpage).I've set my website up so that there are two main columns but are centered into the middle.The id wrap is what centers everything together and the two columns float left or right:

```
     #wrap    {
     width:750px;
     margin:0 auto;
     background-color:#6E6E6E;
     border-left:3px solid #A9E2F3;
     border-right:3px solid #A9E2F3;
     }
     #main    {
     float:left;
     width:496px;
     background:white;
     border-top-right-radius:5px 5px;
     border-bottom-right-radius:5px 5px;
     }
     #sidebar {
     float:right;
     width:250px;
     } `
```

Recently though i tried to add a footer bar like with the navigation bar at the top. this has been set to stay in the warp overall by using "clear:both" and have been trying to make it avoid the "wrap" id altogether.However something has gone wrong and the div's that control the "wrap"and "secondborder" won't fully close. Also as you may see a gray bar has appeared behind and the "wrap"background won't apply(I've set the sidebar background to nothing so that the "wrap" background applies to it. This makes it look a bit neater).I cannot paste the required coding as there is too scattered and is too long(look at the page source on the webpage).
Can anyone provide a solution to the "wrap" background and the "footer" not centering? I have only been learning html and coding for the past 3 months so please forgive me if this is a stupid mistake I've made. The link again to my website where the problem is : http://jimbob.webatu.com/index.html

Comment: create a http://jsfiddle.net/ prototype so we can play with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the overflow: hidden; to your #wrap as such

```
#wrap {
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #6E6E6E;
    border-left: 3px solid #A9E2F3;
    border-right: 3px solid #A9E2F3;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
```

In order for your #footer to act like a footer at the bottom of your page you will have to take it out of your #sidebar and place it after the closing  for #sidebar. This should fix your problems.

To fix the #sidebar being cut off you need to float it left as opposed to right as suc,

```
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    }
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: That seems to have fixed apart from causing the sidebar to shift and cut off some of it. Thank you for fixing the footer and gray bar though

Comment: I have updated my answer to help you with the #sidebar issue.

Comment: Thank-you.That seems to have fixed everything that I couldn't handle.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you need to clear after your floating `div`'s. This tells the browser to stop the floating for the next element. Looking at your HTML I'd add before the `<div id="footer">` `<br style="clear:both" />`

Also, before you close `#wrap` add another `<br style="clear:both" />`

Comment: that's bloating: simply add `overflow:hidden` to the container holding the floated elements.

Comment: @pixeline where do i need to place the `overflow:hidden`?Is it with the "wrap" id?

Answer (score 0):

I just added a new div to your secondborder element: `<div style="clear:both"></div>` that sorted the problem. You were floating and not clearing the sidebar or the main div.

Comment: where do i need to place the div for the `clear:both` for the second border?